# MVC3.0+c#+razor: How to create ONE page where posts are shown and comment create part

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm trying to create a weblog with mvc. I made a database code first with EF. Now I have a page where you can see one post per page. Below I want to show all comments on the post. Thats all working fine. But now I want to make a create comment functionality on that same page.

I'm not sure how to do this? Because this has to create a new object 'comment' instead of the 'post' object I've set as Model in my view. So I've got different models in my view? I don't think that's possible right? Maybe I can just use the 'post' model because it has comments as a list<> in it?

Do I need to use partial views for this or maybe a model view?

Hope you know what I mean and what I'm trying to accomplish. Tnx in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using a partial view. Make a partial view that posts comments to server. Display this partial view below comments list. When user post the comment then submit it via json call and on success make html string of comment and append it in the comments list.
In this way your comment will be posted as well as loaded in comments list without reloading the whole model

Comment: Sounds good Tanveer. Cheers for the explaination. Don't have any experience with json though so have to do some reading up on that. I will give it a try. Tnx.

Comment: This site has good info about json http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/#.T7oRjdxo12A

Answer (score 1):

If your `Post` model contains a `List<Comment>` then you could of course use that. Even if you do go that route, using a ViewModel to wrap all of your model objects is never a bad idea.

Simply for the sake of maintainability, I would use partial views for the different models rendered on your page, but that's is purely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Tnx Nathan. Do I need to connect my view to my postcontroller or commentcontroller?

Comment: @vonRield I'm guessing here, but I suspect your PostController would be used to display the Post and the Comments, but you would want to have your Add Comment form post to your CommentController.

Answer (score 0):

Your post should have a comment collection of some sort. You should be able to just add a non-model-bound form; in your controller, you have your `collection`, just pull the data out of that.

What I mean is: in your view, you'll have something like

`@Html.TextArea("CommentText")`

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection) {
  string commentText = collection["CommentText"];
  Post p = ... ; // Not familiar with EF
  p.Comments.Add(new Comment(commentText));
  p.Save(); // ActiveRecord style, not sure about EF
}
```

It should be pretty straight-forward. I use ActiveRecord on NHibernate, so I'm not sure about Entity Framework specifically. Was there some specific problem you got stuck on?